# How to print last line of a .log file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to read and print last lines of files with extensions like .txt,.logs etc. using batch script.
So as per now I have tried following code on .txt file which is working fine:

```
for /f "delims==" %%a in (D:\error.txt) do set lastline=%%a
echo %lastline%
```

But similarly when I am trying to do this on .log file , I am unable to achieve the desired output, further it gives the error :

```
system cannot find the file
```

Code which I am trying is as follows:

```
for /f "delims==" %%a in (C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs\error.log) do set lastline=%%a
echo %lastline%
```

Please help me guys, and please point me where I am going wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use double-quotes because of spaces in your string. As a result you'll need the `UseBackQ` option in your `For /F`.

```bat
For /F "UseBackQ Delims==" %%A In ("D:\error.txt") Do Set "lastline=%%A"
Echo %lastline%
```

and:

```bat
For /F "UseBackQ Delims==" %%A In ("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs\error.log") Do Set "lastline=%%A"
Echo %lastline%
```